# is there a difference in windows vs. linux for rendering non-latin characters to console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

At Mozilla.org:

```js
const icons = 'Hữu';
const index = 1;
console.log(icons.codePointAt(index));
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(icons.codePointAt(index)));
//expected output:
//> 7919
//> "ữ"
```

This is as I expect.

I run this in `windows powershell`, and the "ữ" (and similar characters) are converted to a "?", and then the codepoint is also changed as a result.  I tried with `String.raw` as well, and it doesn't seem to changing things.

```
>63
>?
```

help??

Comment: What do you mean, "I run this in Windows PowerShell?" PowerShell is its own unique programming environment, separate from Node.

Comment: i run node, in a powershell window....point being it's on windows, and not in a linux environment when I see the difference in ouputs.

Comment: It makes a difference. When I run the above code using a Command Window (i.e., cmd.exe) in Windows 10, using the Node REPL, I get the expected output.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLu2a.png

Comment: thanks the quick responses @HereticMonkey.  It seems something different.  I too can use node REPL mode and get this, but reading in this from my JS file, it wants to convert to "?"s for many of my string characters.  in a web mode, I would be putting in a using-charset type decl...I don't have that here.  But the CMD and PS env's still do the same thing.  Any further advice?

Comment: Sounds like you're saving the file with the wrong encoding. Make sure you save it with UTF-8 encoding or something similar, not just ASCII. If I take that code and save it to a JS file with UTF-8 encoding, it runs fine from cmd. It does not run fine from a PowerShell window; I'm guessing the duplicate @mplungjan pointed to will help with that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, so this was the issue...I had saved the file, it apparently didn't take the encoding correctly.  I had everything else ok, and the duplicate link for PS, I had also resolved prior.  thanks again, I knew it was a stupid error somewhere.